# Convert text file to an array for permanent use in program

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a text file of 1000 words that I want to format an array so I can place it in the program instead of reading the text file each time and creating the array from that.

I tried to find a simple service online but none seem to exist for a simple C# array. Most are for json, xml, rss, etc.

So the output would arrange the words in this fashion:

```
{"word1","word2",...,"wordN"}
```

Here is a [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16641927/SSID.txt) to the text file I want to format.

**Is there a service online to convert the text file or a simple script I can write to convert the text into proper array syntax?**

Any to really be fancy: sort the data alphabetically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using visual studio's search/replace with Regular Expressions turned on, replace `\n` with `","`, that will get you most of the way there since this is one-time.

[image: Find & Replace dialog]

Comment: +1, except that it’s `","`, not `','`. And I would leave the newlines in (`",\n"`) for sanity.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This looks like the most reasonable answer.

Comment: @Nick, Did you turn on regular expressions?

Comment: Nope that was an easy fix, thanks! I used Notepad++ but it's all just the same.

Comment: @Nick: I prefer using Notepad++ too for these conversions. Plus, it supports line sorting out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result = 
    "string[] list =\r\n{\r\n" + 
    string.Join(",\r\n", File
        .ReadLines("SSID.txt")
        .OrderBy(line => line)
        .Select(line => "    " + ToCSharpString(line))) +
    "\r\n};";

File.WriteAllText("Result.cs", result);
```

with

```
static string ToCSharpString(string s)
{
    return s.Contains('\\') || s.Contains('"')
        ? "@\"" + s.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\""
        : "\"" + s + "\"";
}
```

*Result:*

```
string[] list =
{
    "@home",
    "^Y",
    "<any ssid>",
    // ...
    "X-Micro",
    "yale wireless",
    "ZyXEL"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the text file as a resource to your application. Then simply reference the text file and split it by the new line and carriage return letters into an array.

This would prevent extending your scroll bar in your IDE beyond a reasonable amount.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function convertIt(str) {
var array=str.split('\n');
array.sort(); //If you want to sort alphabetically; remove if not
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML='{"'+array.join('","')+'"}';
}
</script>

<textarea id='text'>
</textarea>
<div id='output'></div>
<input type='button' onclick='convertIt(document.getElementById("text").value)' value='Click me!'>
```

Save the above as a .html file, open it in your favourite browser, then paste your list in there and click the button.

Enjoy.

Edit: Ok, so it appears your file's pretty much entirely line breaks. I've revised the code to work bearing that in mind. Tested and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the file is structured with one word per line.

First, sort it on the command line:  `sort <words.txt >words.srt.txt`

1. Load words.srt.txt in Visual Studio.
2. Position to the top of the file.
3. From the Tools menu, select Record Temporary Macro
4. Hit the End key to go to the end of the line
5. Enter a comma (,)
6. Hit the down arrow to go the next line
7. Hit the Home key to go to the start of the line
8. From the Tools menu, select Stop Recording
9. Now, you can select Tools|Run Temporary Macro (or press Ctrl+Shift+P) for each line. If you just hold Ctrl+Shift+P, the keyboard auto repeat will do it for you.

That should take you approximately a minute. Then just add the declaration at the top and the closing brace at the bottom.

Comment: +1: Valid option (albeit somewhat unnecessarily complicated; a regex-enabled replace facility would be much simpler).